# Can I use cedar as my fascia?

Tags: exterior

I am going to put cedar tongue and groove on my soffit, I was wondering if I can just use a 1x6 as the fascia. Thanks in advance. My concern is that it will not last.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. My 26 year old Minnesota home has full cedar treatment and looks great today.

That's not to say that you can simply leave it raw, or seal it once and forget it. Sun and rain constantly work at it, so plan on applying a high-quality penetrating oil product initially and every 3-5 years thereafter.

Comment: In tropical or semi-tropical climates, cedar's useful lifetime is shortened considerably.

Comment: That's true of any wood, right? And since the soffit is already cedar, it's going to be comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it will probably not last as long as other options, cost more, and - my biggest issue - is that it will potentially attract bees and wasps.   But yea it looks great when done right so weigh that in.